# Local database on Android tablet

Tags: android, database

We need to have some kind of app that we can deploy to an Android tablet.  The app must be able to run without internet.  We need to have a database, preferably SQL.

I've been researching the options on how to create a mobile app with local storage and the options are not good.

1. The W3C standard is Indexed DB.  But this is ugly and cumbersome code.  It seems like it would take forever to create a large app.
2. Web storage is a little better
3. We'd like to use jQueryMobile and wrap it in PhoneGap.  Is there a way to install a local server on an Android tablet so we can incorporate PHP and MySQL?  I can't find anything.
4. There's LocalStorage in HTML5, but I'm not sure if that's the way to go.  It is the simplest to code, certainly.

What are your thoughts?  We'd like to use jQueryMobile and PhoneGap so we can deploy to an iPad if we ever decide to go that route.  That's why I didn't include a native Android app with an SQLite database. Or would this be a better way to go (assuming we don't want the iPad option)?

Please let me know when you get a chance.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap does support [local storage in SQLite](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) and hence that is what I would do. Then you can also use the same db working on iPad or migrate to a native application if you find the web approach to be lacking..

Comment: It looks like PhoneGap doesn't support iPad.  At least from the docs.  Is that true?

Comment: I dont use PhoneGap but http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/25124206/iPad seems like it is an option. Personally I am a believer in native apps..

Comment: Agreed.  But we want the option to go to an iPad later, possibly.  That means double the development time.

Comment: Not double since you already know all the business logic and so on, but yes.. I am aware of the downside. Imho if it worth making a mobile app (not website), it is worth making a native one. But I am biased and its just my 2c..